# how to make form in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, axios

https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-boyd-1p8r8?file=/src/components/signup/Signup.jsx In here i am trying to do signup and login in reactjs but when i run this code its login and signup page is not coming.

Any one help me out what is the issue in here https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-boyd-1p8r8?file=/src/components/signup/Signup.jsx

```
  this.handleChangeName = this.handleChangeName.bind(this);

    this.handleChangeMobile = this.handleChangeMobile.bind(this);

    this.handleChangeEmail = this.handleChangeEmail.bind(this);

    this.handleChangePassword = this.handleChangePassword.bind(this);

    this.submituserRegistrationForm = this.submituserRegistrationForm.bind(
      this
    );
  }
```

Please check full code in here   https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-boyd-1p8r8?file=/src/components/signup/Signup.jsx:484-846

Comment: anyone idea why its not working https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-boyd-1p8r8?file=/src/components/signup/Signup.jsx:484-846

Answer (score 1):

You are using React Router V6 and in this version, we don't have Component props for the Route component so change Router part like this

```
<Routes>
   <Route path="/"  element={<Home/>} />

   <Route path="/login" element={<Login/>} />

   <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup/>} />
</Routes>
```

Comment: whole code https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-kapitsa-olm95?file=/src/App.jsx